# É possivel criar miniaturas de imagens com Node.js puro

Tags: node.js, imagem, edição-de-imagens, imagemagick

Bem encontrei uma biblioteca, que é ótima para manipulação de imagens, e funciona prefeitamente, no caso o [GraphicsMagick for node.js](http://aheckmann.github.io/gm/), mas há um problema, pois há dependências de outros *softwares* instalados na maquina onde o node será executado, no caso o [GraphicsMagick](http://www.graphicsmagick.org/index.html), sem ele instalado não rola, pois acredito que "a biblioteca em node seja apenas uma interface para chamadas dos métodos do *software* instalado, que talvez seja desenvolvido em C ou C++ (eu acho)".

Esse é meu 1° projeto com node.js, então não sei muito bem se ele é capaz de fazer isso e por onde começar. E sempre que tento pesquisar por algo como *"Create thumbnail picture with node.js"*, os resultados sempre remetem as bibliotecas citadas anteriormente.

- Então gostaria de saber primeiramente, se é possível criar miniaturas de imagens somente utilizando node.js?
- *"Segundamente"*, se for possível, se há alguma biblioteca que auxilie nessa tarefa?
- E *"terceiramente"*, o caminho das pedras, ou alguma ideia de como implementar isto?

> Obs¹: O meu problema em utilizar a biblioteca citada ([GraphicsMagick for node.js](http://aheckmann.github.io/gm/)), é a necessidade de instalar um *software* na hospedagem, que me pode ser um problema dependendo da politica de segurança da empresa.
>
> Obs²: O único recurso que necessito desta biblioteca é o `resize`.

Comment: Embora deva ser possível, é bem mais simples utilizar uma biblioteca. Seu servidor não te deixa rodar `npm`?

Comment: @bfavaretto, por `npm` eu instalo a biblioteca node, mas também é necessário ter instalado o software na maquina (e é isso que não posso). Já fiz os testes em minha maquina e não funciona sem instalar o software.

Comment: E o ImageMagick, seu servidor suporta? É bem comum, e o módulo [gm](https://github.com/aheckmann/gm) permite escolher usá-lo no lugar do GraphicsMagick.

Comment: @bfavaretto, o problema é que alguns clientes utilizam windows normal como servidor, e isso não é comum em windows, mesmo que seja server.

Comment: @bfavaretto, só uma pergunta, por exemplo uma hospedagem como a do [heroku](https://www.heroku.com/) ou [openshift](https://www.openshift.com/), já tem isso disponível?

Comment: Não sei, Fernando, mas no site deles deve dizer.

Comment: Eu uso o OpenShift e eles te permitem acesso ssh e por lá você instala essas coisas com o gerenciador de pacotes yum. Mas, cuidado, usar o mesmo servidor para HTTP e compressão de imagens não é performático. É melhor usar algo como Resque (Ruby) ou Celery (Python)

Comment: Encontrei esse artigo. Talvez ao menos parte dele lhe seja útil:

http://tonyspiro.com/uploading-resizing-images-fly-node-js-express/

Comment: @PedroVinícius, cai no mesmo problema, olhe no fim do artigo `brew install imagemagick`, é necessário instalar o ImageMagick, mas mesmo assim obrigado pela ajuda.

Answer (score 4):

Olá, é possível criar miniaturas através do Node.JS, porém, exigirá um conhecimento bem mais avançado.
Atualmente usando bibliotecas externas encontramos os seguintes problemas:

- Os módulos npm necessitam que você pré-instale alguma biblioteca como
  a ImageMagick;
- Necessidade de iniciar um novo processo externo para cada imagem a
  ser processada.

Existe uma biblioteca chamada [LWIP](https://github.com/EyalAr/lwip) ela trabalha com imagens **JPG**, o criador [Eyal Arubas](http://eyalarubas.com/), pensou exatamente na sua idéia em minimizar os problemas com manipulações de imagens excluindo no máximo a dependência de outras bibliotecas, sendo necessário apenas um *módulo npm*.

**Como usar a LWIP:**

Realize a instalação utilizando o comando:

```
npm install lwip
```

Crie o arquivo server.js:

```
require('lwip').open('sheldon.jpg', function(err, image){

  // manipulação do evento, caso não consiga abrir a img.
  image.batch()
    .resize(45, 45)  

    .writeFile('output.jpg', function(err){
      // manipulação do evento
    });

});
```

**Método `.resize()` do LWIP**:

```
image.resize(width, height, inter, callback)
```

1. **width {Integer}**: Largura em pixels.
2. **height {Integer}**: Altura em pixels(opcional). Se não especificado,
   será calculado pela largura..
3. **inter {String}**: Método interpolation(opcional). Por default usa-se
   "lanczos", possíveis valores:

   - "nearest-neighbor"
   - "moving-average"
   - "linear"
   - "grid"
   - "cubic"
   - "lanczos"
4. **callback {Function(err, image)}**

Comment: Me parece uma boa opção, não testei ainda (pois é um projeto particular), mas olhei a documentação e é algo que esperava. Só uma pergunta você citou que: "ela trabalha com imagens JPG", e somente JPG? Na documentação não achei nada citando essa restrição, mas vi que todos os exemplos são com JPG. Você utiliza essa biblioteca? Se sim, ela tem um bom desempenho?

Comment: Infelizmente ela trabalha apenas com JPG, caso você tente enviar um PNG ela retornará: `PNG is not yet supported`. O desempenho dela é bom, já utilizei e seu tempo de resposta é melhor que o esperado.

Comment: Thanks for using the module, I hope it's helpful. PNG support is [planned for v0.0.2](https://github.com/EyalAr/lwip/issues?labels=&milestone=2&page=1&state=open).

Comment: Pelo que percebi o autor já adiciono suporte a [PNG](https://github.com/EyalAr/lwip#png) e [GIF](https://github.com/EyalAr/lwip#gif). Não testei pois atualmente não estou desenvolvendo para node.js. (@EyalAr, EN: _From what I understand the author has add support [PNG](https://github.com/EyalAr/lwip#png) and [GIF](https://github.com/EyalAr/lwip#gif). I not tested for I am not currently developing for node.js_).